# Error : '(' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I tried to match STRING_LITERAL for this following assignment 
 
String
A string literal includes zero or more characters enclosed by double
quotes (”). Use escape sequences (listed below) to represent special
characters within a string. Remember that the quotes are not part of
the string. It is a compile-time error for a new line or EOF character
to appear after the opening (”) and before the closing matching (”).
All the supported escape sequences are as follows:
 
\b backspace
\f form feed
\r carriage return
\n newline
\t horizontal tab
\’ single quote
\ backslash
For a double quote (”) inside a string, a single quote (’) must be written before it: ’” double quote
For example:
”This is a string containing tab \t”
”He asked me: ’”Where is John?’””

At the beginning my code would be like this :

```
// Every char that isn't ESC_ILLEGAL or is ESC_SEQ 
STRING_LITERAL: '"' STR_CHAR* '"';

fragment STR_CHAR: ~ESC_ILLEGAL| ESC_SEQ;

fragment ESC_SEQ: ([\\] [btnfr'\\]) | [{'"}];

fragment ESC_ILLEGAL: (([\\] ~[btnfr'\\]) | ['] ~["]);
```

But due to the ANTLR syntax problem, I had to write inline ESC_ILLEGAL, my final code would be like this:

```
STRING_LITERAL: '"' STR_CHAR* '"';

fragment STR_CHAR: ~(([\\] ~[btnfr'\\]) | ['] ~["]) | ESC_SEQ;

fragment ESC_SEQ: ([\\] [btnfr'\\]) | [{'"}];
```

Now ANTLR throw out an error: `'(' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element` 
I tried to search for this error, even used De Morgan changing my STR_CHAR to please ANTLR ( but that doesn't work cause AND isn't supported by ANTLR ). By the way, I'm not pretty sure if my STRING_LITERAL is right, if u can give some advice for that, it would be nice.  I'm purely new to ANTLR so maybe many things that I did seem so wrong but please help me if u can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negating character sets inside the lexer can only be done when there is a single character in the negated set. So this is valid:

```
FOO : ~(('a' | 'b') | 'c');
```

but this isn't:

```
FOO : ~(('ab') | 'c'); // 'ab' cannot be negated
```

Your problem is this:

```
~(([\\] ~[btnfr'\\]) | ['] ~["])
```

you can't negate whatever is matched by `(([\\] ~[btnfr'\\]) | ['] ~["])`.

Answer (score 2):

This task is made of two parts:

- Collect all parts that comprise a string.
- Apply semantic to some of its content.

The first part can be accomplished with these simple rules:

```
String:
    DOUBLE_QUOTE InnerString* DOUBLE_QUOTE
;

fragment InnerString:
    SINGLE_QUOTE DOUBLE_QUOTE InnerString SINGLE_QUOTE DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | .
;

DOUBLE_QUOTE: '"';
SINGLE_QUOTE: '\'';
```

Comparing that to your solution it appears that this one doesn't specifically deal with escape sequences. That's because handling errors (i.e. wrong sequences) would be more difficult, if you would define the sequences in the grammar. Handling escape sequences means to apply meaning (semantic) to a part of the string. And semantic handling is better done in a separate step after the parse run.

In the semantic step you would scan your token text for any `\<letter>` squence and convert them to the actuall target value. If you encounter a sequence that is not valid you can print a nice error message, which would not be possible if the allowed escape codes would appear in the lexer grammar. The parse run would just stop with a mysterious message like "no viable alt".

Comment: Thank you so much, it gives me a big stress release and also saves me a lot of useless time trying to fix it cause I thought I have to handle escape sequence in lexical step.